# image overflowing in div

Tags: html, css

I am sure this is really easy but I am facing issue the image is overflowing the card-box section
Wanted to achieve similar to this

```css
*::before,
*::after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: "poppins", "sans-serif";
}

body{
  background-color: hsl(30, 38%, 92%);
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  z-index: -1;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.product{
  display: flex;
  max-width: 700px;
  /* justify-content: center;
  align-items: center; */   
}

.card-box {
  margin: 1em 2em;
  max-width: 400px;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 1.5em;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.image{
  height: 100vh;
  width: 50vw;
  background-color: aqua;

}

img{
  max-width: 100%;
  height:100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Product</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <section class="card-box">
            <section class="image">
                <img src="https://codehelp-product-card.netlify.app/images/mug.jpg" alt="" class="cofee-mug">
            </section>
            <section class="details">
                <p>coffee mug</p>
            </section>
        </section>
    </div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

tried to change height and width of container, tried  changing display of image class to block but no change is shown in output
My output:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/84KMg.png)

Expecting
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lj8E0.png)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure flex is the best answer to do that. Personally I would prefer grid.

Display grid for the card, position left and right (image, details) inside.

```css
*::before,
*::after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: "poppins", "sans-serif";
}

body {
  background-color: hsl(30, 38%, 92%);
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
  z-index: -1;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.product {
  display: flex;
  max-width: 700px;
  /* justify-content: center;
        align-items: center; */
}

.card-box {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  margin: 1em 2em;
  max-width: 400px;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 1.5em;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.image {
  grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 2;
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
}

.details {
  grid-area: 1 / 2 / 2 / 3;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 1.5em 0 0 1.5em;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <section class="card-box">
    <section class="image">
      <img src="https://codehelp-product-card.netlify.app/images/mug.jpg" alt="" class="cofee-mug">
    </section>
    <section class="details">
      <p>coffee mug</p>
    </section>
  </section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be a way to solve it: just add **style="overflow:hidden;"** to your code. Or you can try to use **"border-radius:20px;"** to hide it.

```css
*::before,
*::after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: "poppins", "sans-serif";
}

body{
  background-color: hsl(30, 38%, 92%);
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  z-index: -1;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.product{
  display: flex;
  max-width: 700px;
  /* justify-content: center;
  align-items: center; */   
}

.card-box {
  margin: 1em 2em;
  max-width: 400px;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 1.5em;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.image{
  height: 100vh;
  width: 50vw;
  background-color: aqua;

}

img{
  max-width: 100%;
  height:100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Product</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <section class="card-box" style="overflow:hidden;">
            <section class="image">
                <img src="https://codehelp-product-card.netlify.app/images/mug.jpg" alt="" class="cofee-mug">
            </section>
            <section class="details">
                <p>coffee mug</p>
            </section>
        </section>
    </div>
    
</body>
</html>
```